# Angular 2/4 img src

Tags: angular

I'm simply trying to render an image in a component.  I can't seem to find a decent answer that works.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Enviroment:**

angular/cli 1.1.2

node 8.1.0

OS win x64

angular -v 4.2.5

**What I have tired (HTML):**

```
<img [src]={{imgUrl}} />
<img [src]="imgUrl" />

<img src={{imgUrl}} />
<img src="imgUrl" />

<img ng-src="imgUrl" />

<img src="assets/images/img.jpg" />
<!-- and a few more -->
```

**With .ts file like:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  imgUrl = "";

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.imgUrl = 'assets/images/img.jpg';
     // i have also tried
     // ~/assets/...
     // ./assets/...
     // etc
  }


}
```

**Project structure:**

```
src
--app
----home
------ts-files
--assets
----images
------img.jpg
```

I have also tried moving the file from assets to the same ts folder, and some other places.

But I only get the same 404 error.

GET http://localhost:4200/assets/images/img.jpg 404 (Not Found)

**UPDATE**

**.angular-cli.json content (autogenerated):**

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on the error, looks like your local server doesn't know about the static files. Have you checked `.angular-cli.json` file in `app.assets`?

Comment: No sir, I have not. I'm still new to TS :( What am I looking for?

Comment: Sorry, miss! This is included om the .angular-cli.json: "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico" ]

Comment: (Not "sir" :-/). `.angular-cli.json` is the configuration file for angular-cli. You should be able to find it at the root of your project next to README.md and package.json.

Comment: Quick test: can you view the favicon? http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico

Comment: Yes, I can see the favicon when i brows to localhost:4200/favicon.ico

Comment: Also if i build the project `ng build --prod` I get an assets/images/img.jpg folder

Comment: As @stealththeninja noticed, ur angular.cli.json misses images. Try add it - `"assets": [
        "assets", "images"`

Comment: @J.D. images is a subdirectory of assets so it's included, no need to add it unless it's sibling to assets.

Comment: @J.D. that actually worked.. and now if i remote `"images",` it also works T_T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `<img src="/assets/images/img.jpg">` doesn't work? Note the leading '/' in it. When you're using the Angular CLI, if you run `ng build` it should create a dist directory in your project with the built static Web files. Can you confirm that the `assets/images/img.jpg` file is in your generated output from `ng build`?

Comment: Yes, during the build the folder was created with the image. And I did try with and without a leading / and more.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @J.D. in the comments section.

In `.angular-cli.json` add the name of your directory containing images to assets. Ex: directory to add is images  `"assets": ["assets", "images" ]`

> As @stealththeninja noticed, ur angular.cli.json misses images. Try add it - "assets": [ "assets", "images"

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

`<img ng-src="{{imgUrl}}" />`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: The question is about Angular 4. You're linking to the documentation of AngularJS 1.x, which is another, different framework.